# Есть ли аналог string.split() для array?

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы такую функцию, написать сам пока не могу, не могу придумать как делить именно массив по позициям.
Она должна работать примерно так `arraySplit(array, el => return el ? true : false);`
И из массива элементов

```
[item, item, item, NOPE, item, item, NOPE, item, item]
```

Делать

```
[[item,item,item], [item,item,item], [item, item]]
```

Решение от DreamChild

```
export function arraySplit(el, separator) {

const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(el));
let tmp = [];

if (!items) {
    return tmp;
}

let res = [tmp];

for (let item of items) {
    if (!separator(item)) {
        tmp.push(item);
    } else {
        tmp = [];
        res.push(tmp);
    }
}
return res;
}
```

Comment: это называется группировка, и для разбития на группы можно использовать метод reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
function split(arr, delimiter) {       
    var tmp = [];
    if(!arr)
      return tmp;
    var res = [tmp];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] !== delimiter)
            tmp.push(arr[i]); 
        else {
            tmp = [];
            res.push(tmp);
        }
    }  
   return res;
}
```

Comment: работает, но я не совсем понимаю как именно.
Я переписал на es5 синтаксис.

Comment: @DimenSi это и есть ES5. Использовать возможности ES6 я не стал, так как до сих пор еще не все браузеры его  поддерживают. Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте. Никакой особой JS магии тут нет

Comment: var точно не es5. В общем не в этом дело. Объясните почему возвращаете tmp, при пустом массиве и я так понял, если элемент попадает под фильтр, мы создаем обнуляем массив и запихиваем его в res?

Comment: @DimenSi вы что-то путаете. Объявление переменных с помощью var в JS есть испокон веков, с самых первых версий. Вот скажем let появился только с ES6, но let тут не используется.

Comment: let появился в es5, и в es5 можно использовать var, но никто его уже не использует.

Comment: @DimenSi По первому вашему вопросу: если входной массив пуст, то разбивать там нечего, поэтому можно сразу вернуть пустой массив. А tmp как раз на тот момент пуст

Comment: @DimenSi по второму вопросу: если мы сталкиваемся с символом-разделителем, то это значит, что в результирующий массив нужно добавить новый элемент. Для этого мы создаем новый временный массив и сразу же заносим его в результирующий

Comment: let появился в es6 и отсутствует в es5, напутали всё что можно :)

Comment: Боже геморные обозначения.
Я считал es2015 это es5

Comment: @DimenSi let появился именно в ES6. вот тут почитайте: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: В общем благодарю за ответ.